# Redirect all numbered PHP pages to home

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

A legacy PHP site that I'm replacing contains a static numbered PHP file for every pagination of content, that is:

example.com/pictures-1.php

example.com/pictures-2.php

example.com/pictures-3.php
.
.
.

example.com/pictures-x.php

Where x can be any integer up to 999.

How do set up a rewrite in .htaccess to 301 redirect all of the above pages to home, i.e. https://www.example.com?

Thanks.

Comment: This link is good for a start: http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/redirects/setting-up-a-301-permanent-redirect-via-htaccess

Comment: Did you try to write this rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple thing to do what you want is:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/pictures-(\d+).php
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://example.com [L,R=301,NC]
```

You can of course extend this to also pass the page that was rewritten using the following:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/pictures-(\d+).php
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://example.com?page=%1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

There's a handly little tool that helps with .htaccess at http://htaccess.mwl.be/